# Error Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor )

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently learning ASP.NET and having some problems. When I try to run the Swagger, it shows some problems with my Services.
Here my files:
**IEmployeeService.cs**

```
namespace ClinicAPI.Services
{
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        public Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(EmployeeDto employee);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeService.cs**

```
public class EmployeeService : ControllerBase,IEmployeeService
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public EmployeeService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, EmployeeService employeeService)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateUser")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(EmployeeDto employee)
        {
            var userExist = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(employee.UserName);

            if (userExist != null)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Massage = "User Already Exist" });
            ApplicationUser user = new()
            {
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                EmployeeFullName = employee.EmployeeFullName,
                DateOfBirth = employee.DateOfBirth,
                IdentificationNumber = employee.IdentificationNumber,
                DepartmentName = employee.DepartmentName,
                Gender = employee.Gender,
                UserName = employee.UserName,
                PhoneNumber = employee.UserName,
            };
            employee.Password = "123456";
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, employee.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Massage = "Tạo nhân viên thất bại" });
            }
            return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Massage = "Created Successfully" });
        }
```

I believe the CreateUser works well without the Service. and this is the controller
**EmployeeController**

```
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

        public EmployeeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, IEmployeeService employeeService)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _employeeService = employeeService;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] EmployeeDto request)
        {
            var status = await _employeeService.CreateUser(request);
            return Ok(status);
        }
```

The EmployeeDto has those properties I tried to assign in EmployeeServices. And here is my Configurations, I added AddScoped in **Startup.cs**.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ClinicAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
        }
```

The controller works well without Service and Dto, but it had some errors when I tried to reconstruct in another way (with dto and service).
It shows:'

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: ClinicAPI.Services.IEmployeeService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ClinicAPI.Services.EmployeeService': Unable to resolve service for type 'ClinicAPI.Services.EmployeeService' while attempting to activate 'ClinicAPI.Services.EmployeeService'.)'
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ClinicAPI.Services.EmployeeService' while attempting to activate 'ClinicAPI.Services.EmployeeService'.

I tried many solutions searched but it didn't work.

Comment: `EmployeeService` has a dependency on itself. So in order to make a `EmployeeService`, you need to first make a `EmployeeService` instance, which is an infinite loop and can't happen.

Comment: Side note, why is `EmployeeService` acting like a service _and_ a controller? Why not move MVC Actions to `EmployeeController`?

Comment: Yeah, I have just learned these a few days and messed up with those terms. When the StatusCode needs a ControllerBase and it did not show an error when I combined those two, I didn't see the problem. @Nkosi answer below helps me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion here. You appear to be mixing up the controller and service responsibilities.

Simplify the service to its core functionality. There is no need for the service to be derived from `ControllerBase`

```
public interface IEmployeeService {
    public Task<Response> CreateUser(EmployeeDto employee);
}

public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService {
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public EmployeeService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<Response> CreateUser(EmployeeDto employee) {
        var userExist = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(employee.UserName);
        if (userExist != null)
            return  new Response { Status = "Error", Massage = "User Already Exist" };

        ApplicationUser user = new() {
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            EmployeeFullName = employee.EmployeeFullName,
            DateOfBirth = employee.DateOfBirth,
            IdentificationNumber = employee.IdentificationNumber,
            DepartmentName = employee.DepartmentName,
            Gender = employee.Gender,
            UserName = employee.UserName,
            PhoneNumber = employee.UserName,
        };
        //employee.Password = "123456";

        var created = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, employee.Password);
        if (!created.Succeeded)
            return new Response { Status = "Error", Massage = "Tạo nhân viên thất bại" };
        
        return new Response { Status = "Success", Massage = "Created Successfully" };
    }
}
```

Update the controller to depend on the service

```
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService employeeService) {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    [HttpPost("Register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] EmployeeDto request) {
        Response response = await _employeeService.CreateUser(request);
        if(response.Status != "Success") {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, response);
        }
        return Ok(response);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Can I ask how to write HTTP Get to get all the users from the Users table? I use asp.net identity. The return type error struggling me.

Comment: @ĐạtNguyễn what do you mean by return type error?